# Is there a way to get the main paragraph from Wikipedia using JavaScript only?

Tags: javascript, wikipedia

From [Wikipedia](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Google):

> Google is an American multinational corporation specializing in
>   Internet-related services and products. These include search,
>   cloud computing, software, and online advertising technologies.
>   Most of its profits are derived from AdWords. Google was founded
>   by Larry Page and Sergey Brin while they were Ph.D. students at
>   Stanford University. Together they own about 16 percent of its shares.
>   They incorporated Google as a privately held company on September 4,
>   1998. An initial public offering followed on August 19, 2004. Its mission statement from the outset was "to organize the world's
>   information and make it universally accessible and useful", and its
>   unofficial slogan was "Don't be evil". In 2006 Google moved to
>   headquarters in Mountain View, California, nicknamed the Googleplex.

How can I get the main paragraph from Wikipedia using JavaScript only?

Comment: Don't make a question linking to this question

Answer (score 2, accepted):

To avoid cross-domain issues, you can do this using JSONP:

```
$.getJSON("http://en.wikipedia.org/w/api.php?action=query&prop=extracts&exintro&format=json&callback=?&titles=Google", function(data){
    var page = data.query.pages;
    var intro = "";
    for (var key in page) {
        var obj = page[key];
        intro = obj.extract;
    }
    console.log(intro);
});
```

Comment: Ok will try that. It looks promising. Thanks

Answer (score 3):

This gets you the raw [HTML](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/HTML):

```
$('#mw-content-text').children('p')[0];
```

You could use this with some sort of scraper. Maybe script something with [PhantomJS](http://phantomjs.org/).

Comment: that and previous answer could work well together

Answer (score 1):

Google has already done this job and is exposing all this information as [RDF](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Resource_Description_Framework)/[JSON](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/JSON) graphs through the [Freebase API](https://developers.google.com/freebase/).

You can also get the raw [HTML](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/HTML) and then parse the content.

Comment: Looks promising, Currently setting it up.